# Fresh Magento installation gives empty response (all browsers)

Tags: magento-1.7, error

I even cant see the install-page!

No PHP-Errors. Just ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on Chrome for Example.

Somebody have clue what could cause this?

It seems to me like some type of miss configuration on the webserver itself but want to get 100% sure.

Thx in forward

Comment: please turn on error output in the index.php. uncomment `ini_set('display_errors',1);` and make sure Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); is on. Also check the apache error logs for any errors

Comment: Yeah, I should have said, that I turned that all on! I have no access to the Apache Log, but Provider says there are no problems.

Comment: hm okay, put a `die('test');` on line one and see if it actually reaches the index.php

Comment: I can tell that the problem occurs after on/after calling Mage::run(). Variables are ok.